# Colors.white.withOpacity not working on Flutter Web app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

### Problem description

I am not able to set white color with some opacity in Flutter on the Web.

Either

```
Colors.white24
```

or

```
Color(0x3DFFFFFF)
```

or even (suggested by @biruk-is)

```
Colors.white.withOpacity(0.24)
```

fail to show in Web app. It works as expected on Android and Windows, though...

### How to reproduce?

Simply create a new Flutter App, with the standard template and modify the `Scaffold` as

```dart
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white24,
  body: Center(
    child: Text(
      'Test text',
    ),
  ),
);
```

by doing this you get a colored background in Android or Windows, but on the web (both Chrome and Edge) show a white background...

[image]

### Question:

Am i doing something wrong or did i misunderstood anything? Please kindly let me know (i am new to flutter (and web!) developement).

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you filed an error report on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Posible solution

If by using

```dart
Colors.white.withOpacity(0.24)
```

you do get the color white, you might still be able to get your desired color by calling

```dart
Colors.black.withOpacity(0.74)
```

If that is your case read the "*What causes this issue?*" section below.

### What causes this issue?

The problem is a background color set up in the tree. If that background color is set to black, then setting `Colors.black.withOpacity` will always return black, or if the background color is white then setting `Colors.white.withOpacity` will always return white.

In my case, running

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Container());
}
```

returns a black screen on Android, Windows and iOS, but a white screen in Chrome and Edge.

I also found out that there is already [an issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/107596) in flutter that reports this problem.

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

```
const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.3)
```

it gives me grey with 30% opacity.

Answer (score -2):

use this:

```
Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5)
```